# Querying users with Baasbox API

Tags: php, rest, baasbox

I am trying to retrieve a filtered list of users using the REST API interface on BAASBOX.

Within the visibleToRegisteredUsers field I have a field called company and want to filter on that.

The URL I am using to filter is: http://myurl.com:9000/users?where=company%3D'$company'

If I don't use the query I can get all the users returned, if I use the filter nothing is returned so I must be filtering incorrectly. Does anyone know how I would apply the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer back from the developers :)

Use the URL http://myurl.com:9000/users?where=visibleByRegisteredUsers.company%3D%27company